# Bubble sort options. Need to add a (print_bubble) procedure that prints the bubble displacement

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I already tried several things but its just not working, im just starting with C. I would also like to add a counter for the number of swaps done, but cannot come up with the spot to write it. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 

// A function to implement bubble sort 
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

       // Last i elements are already in place    
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
} 

/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
    printf("\n"); 
} 



// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    bubbleSort(arr, n); 
    printf("Sorted array: \n"); 
    printArray(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Add `int counter = 0;` and `++counter;` in appropriate places?

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "the bubble displacement"? Is that where you are comparing?

Comment: @Caleth With the "bubble displacement" I mean the number of swaps made by the program. The total number, sorry if Im being a little bit redundant, english is not my main language.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `{}` to deliminate scopes, it's easy to find a place to count swaps.

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       
   {
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
       {
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
           {
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
              // increase swap count here
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hackish way is simply to add a global `size_t nswaps` and increment `nswaps++;` in `swap()`.

**Pass a Pointer to Counter**

A more correct way, if you cannot change the return type of `bubblesort()` from `void`, would be to add a parameter that allows passing a pointer to a counter to `bubblesort (... size_t *nswaps)` and then in your `if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) { ...; (*nswaps)++; }`. E.g.

```
// A function to implement bubble sort 
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n, size_t *nswaps) 
{ 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

    // Last i elements are already in place    
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
            (*nswaps)++;                     /* increment counter */
        }
}
```

and then in `main()` initialize your counter to zero and pass a pointer to the counter by using the `'&'` (address of) operator, increment the value at that address in `bubblesort()` and then you have the updated value available back in `main()`

```
// Driver program to test above functions 
int main (void) 
{ 
    int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    size_t nswaps = 0;                            /* add counter */
    bubbleSort(arr, n, &nswaps); 
    printf("Sorted array in (%zu swaps): \n", nswaps); 
    printArray(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

**Provide a Meaningful Return of Count**

You can also change the return type of `bubblesort()` to `size_t` and simply return the count, e.g.

```
// A function to implement bubble sort 
size_t bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    size_t nswaps = 0;
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

    // Last i elements are already in place    
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
            nswaps++; 
        }

    return nswaps;
}
```

then in `main()` just capture the return:

```
// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    int arr[] = {64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 
    size_t nswaps = 0;
    nswaps = bubbleSort(arr, n); 
    printf("Sorted array in (%zu swaps): \n", nswaps); 
    printArray(arr, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I literally cannot thank you enough! It worked just as I wished, now, I have some sort of problem, I coded a section so every iteration of the bubble sort could be printed. However, I need to specify at the left side of every printing the variable "j" and on the other side the variable "i" (those who are being swapped). Im almost sure im writing something wrong... 

``` 

```

Comment: You are welcome. If the your current sort problem is related, you can add a comment here and I will try and help. If it is a different issue, then you probably should ask another question. Above, your sort algorithm worked fine (though you should probably add `{...}` to enclose everything below each `for` loop so you don't confuse yourself if you add another statement below each loop.) In other words `for (...) for (...) if (...) { ... }` only works if there are no other statement below each loop `for (...) { for (...) { if (...) {...} } }` works regardless.

Comment: That should be `size_t *s` as the parameter. You are passing a pointer. (e.g. a normal variable that holds the address to something else as its value). By using `size_t s`, the function receives a copy of `s` so any changes made to `s` are never seen back in the calling function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will make a new question...

Comment: Check the comment above first -- I may have answered it `:)`